# В узле "Зависимости" нет команды "Добавить ссылку"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Win 10, VS19 16.6.2
Согласно [официальной документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DRU-RU%26k%3Dk(VS.ReferenceManager)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019#add-a-reference), для добавления ссылки надо
**в обозревателе решений** щелкнуть правой кнопкой мыши на узел **Зависимости** и выбрать команду **Добавить ссылку**. Но вместо этой команды предлагают три других:

[image: Problem]

Мне надо добавить в проект (библиотека классов .NET Core 3.1) ссылку на сборку System.Windows.Forms, и ни одна из них не может этого сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Ссылки на WinForms добавляются через `.csproj`.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Если вы установите `Project/PropertyGroup/UseWindowsForms` в `true`, то ссылки добавятся автоматически. Такая же история и с WPF, только вместо `UseWindowsForms` – `UseWPF`. Для подробной информации о `.csproj` можете посмотреть [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj).

Comment: А как быть с другими сборками? На том же [метаните] (https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.32.php), да и вообще во всех гайдах есть только "Добавить ссылку"

Comment: @duck_alan там используется .NET Framwork. *Никогда* его не используйте. .NET Core во *всём* лучше .NET Framework. то, что он там используется говорит о старости гайда.

Comment: @duck_alan так я вам помог?